# upload Code First DB to web server

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I have created my first website and I have used Code First to create the database on SQLExpress.

Now I wish to publish my website on a server, which only accepts SQL Server databases.

How can I do this?  Is there a function in EF5 or VS to let me create the database, and take a .bak file and upload it on the server?

Or is there a better way to go around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is the right approach however I found an easy way to do it.

I created a new SQL Server 2008 database with the same name as my database, and imported the data from the database in the App_Data folder.  Then I changed my connectionstrings to point to this database (in SQL Server) and could then transfer it on my server